# @Transaction how to get updated via multiple threads

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have been facing this issue for a while.

```
@Service
public class SomeService{

   @Autowired
   private Repo repo;

   @Transactional
   public void update(int id){
     repo.findById(id).ifPresent(entity -> entity.setName(entity.getName() + "-name"));
   }

}
```

My problem is that - often times same id is passed by 2 different threads to update the entity. I see only the last update in the entity.

That is -

`entity.getName()` by default will return `some`.
the expected result is - `some-name-name`
but what i see in the end is `some-name`.

The problem seems to be findbyId is executed at the same time by 2 different threads and leave that entity in this state.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use optimistic locking with retry to make sure both updates end up committing.

Have a look at this question: [Spring Optimistic Locking:How to retry transactional method till commit is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144010/spring-optimistic-lockinghow-to-retry-transactional-method-till-commit-is-succe)

The key is to use Spring Retry and capture the optimistic locking exception.