# Does Spring's JdbcTemplate close the connection if an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, exception, jdbctemplate

When Spring catches an SQLException, does it close the prepared statement, result set, and/or connection before throwing it's own DataAccessException (runtime) exception?

I have a developer who wants to create an AOP aspect to catch these exceptions and log and/or close the connection.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="dataAccessOperation()", throwing="exception")
public void doRecoveryActions(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, DataAccessException exception) {
     // log and/or close connection
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Yes.

That's the whole point of `JdbcTemplate` - it handles all kinds of boilerplate actions including release of all resources. See [12. Data access with JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html).

Comment: The documentation describes translating the exceptions and it talks about closing connections, but nothing specifically states that it closes connections when catching exceptions. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, documentation seems to be not very verbose in this case, but `JdbcTemplate` actually takes care of closing connections in the case of exception (though when used with Spring-managed transactions connections are actually closed by transactio manager, but it doesn't matter).

Comment: In the case of a unchecked/runtime exception, will jdbctemplate also clean up and close the connection?

Comment: Yes - it will catch an unchecked/runtime exception and close the connection, but only if that exception is not caught higher up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think your developer should take a look at [springs transaction managemant](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) capabilities. You can use AOP to advice logging, rollback behavior and even [retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451260/how-to-configure-retryadvice-and-exceptiontranslation-for-deadlocks-using-nhibern) or other exception handling actions to react completly declarative.